# Comparing Two Batches of Files

Tags: file-handling, file-comparison, file-sorting

I have two hard drives. Hard Drive (A) is the most recent, but is potentially missing some files from Hard Drive (B). The two drives have the same file structure, and the folders are named the same. (B) might have files that are missing from (A), but I don't want to overwrite any existing files in (A) as if they exist in both, (A)'s files are up to date.

I'm working on a mac, but if there's a solution that requires a windows PC, it might be possible to use one instead.

Am I missing a really simple way of solving this without tediously trawling through each folder and it's sub-folders? Or is there a piece of software that could do this, or even script?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The terminal command 'rsync' is exactly what's needed. See [Here for info](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html)